# Project xx.xcodeproj cannot be opened because it is missing its project.pbxproj file

Tags: xcode, git

Opening Xcode project file gives the following error:

> Project xx.xcodeproj cannot be opened because it is missing its project.pbxproj file.

I created a project on the Mac provided by the company where I work and pushed it to source control.
I cloned the project on my personal Mac and when I try to open this project, it says:

> Project xxProject xx.xcodeproj cannot be opened because it is missing its project.pbxproj file.

Comment: That file should be in the xx.xcodeproj folder in your project folder so "../xx/xx.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj". Is it there? Is it in your git repository? What kind of troubleshooting have you done?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it exists in the local repo of my office laptop but doesn't exist on the remote repo.